# Auto upload crashlogs iPhone

Tags: iphone, crash-dumps

Quick question for you.

Will I have any issues with the Appstore approval process if my app periodically checks for crashlogs and uploads it to a server? Is this even possible? If not, can I have something like a global exception handler and make my app terminate gracefully, while being able to upload exception messages to the server?

Thanks, 
Teja

Comment: Apple does this for you, through iTunes Connect. They'll even give you a breakdown of which crashes occur most frequently.

Comment: Wow, neat. So I have a few users/testers for whom I'm loading the app through the ad-hoc deployment. What would be a good way of getting crash logs from them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For apps distributed through the App Store, Apple will deliver the crash logs to you through iTunes Connect.

For Ad-Hoc builds, you will need to have your users send you the crash logs. When the iPhone is synchronized with iTunes, it copies all the crash logs onto the computer. Here are the locations where they are stored on various OSes:

**Mac OS X**: `~/Library/Logs/CrashReporter/MobileDevice/[DEVICE_NAME]`

**Windows XP**: `C:\Documents and Settings\[USERNAME]\Application Data\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter\[DEVICE_NAME]`

**Windows Vista**: `C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Roaming\Apple computer\Logs\CrashReporter\MobileDevice\[DEVICE_NAME]`

(I got these paths from Google; haven't verified them myself. But someone can comment if they're wrong).