# iPhone App works in simulator but not on device (NSUserDefaults)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios-simulator, nsuserdefaults

I have some code, which works perfect in the simulator, but i cant run it on a real iPhone device and i dont get the reason:

```
- (void)loadView {
 self.title = @"Optionen";
 [super loadView];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {    
 [super viewDidLoad];

 NSMutableArray *strArray = [NSMutableArray new];
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 if ([[prefs stringForKey:@"facebook"] length] > 0 ) {
  [strArray addObject: [prefs stringForKey:@"facebook"]];
 }
 else {
  [strArray addObject:@"YES"];
 } 


 if ([[prefs stringForKey:@"twitter"] length] > 0 ) {
  [strArray addObject: [prefs stringForKey:@"twitter"]];
 }
 else {
  [strArray addObject:@"YES"];
 }


 if ([[prefs stringForKey:@"pm"] length] > 0 ) {
  [strArray addObject: [prefs stringForKey:@"pm"]];
 }
 else {
  [strArray addObject:@"YES"];
 }

 [facebookSwitch setOn:[[strArray objectAtIndex:0] boolValue]];
 [twitterSwitch setOn:[[strArray objectAtIndex:1] boolValue]];
 [pmSwitch setOn:[[strArray objectAtIndex:2] boolValue]]; 

 [strArray release];
}

-(IBAction) change:(id) sender {
 NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

 if (facebookSwitch.on) {
  [prefs setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"facebook"];  
 }
 else {
  [prefs setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"facebook"];
 }


 if (twitterSwitch.on) {
  [prefs setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"twitter"];  
 }
 else {
  [prefs setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"twitter"];
 }


 if (pmSwitch.on) {
  [prefs setObject:@"YES" forKey:@"pm"];  
 }
 else {
  [prefs setObject:@"NO" forKey:@"pm"];
 }

 [prefs synchronize];
}
```

Is it a problem with my use of NSUserDefaults?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't work? Any errors in log?

Comment: Well, thats my main problem at the moment: i don't have a device here to debug it, so someon else tested it for, so i only know the app gets closed. I know thats not a very good basis to solve the problem, but i just cant understand why it doesnt works on the device.

Comment: Has the tester successfully loaded your programs before?  i.e. Are you certain it's not a provisioning problem of some sort?

Comment: Yes, its just one view (this view) which doesn't works, the other views works without problems. And this is the only view where i use NSUserDefaults, thats why i thougt this could be the problem but everything should be ok with my implementation.

Comment: In this context, I can't really say I see anything wrong anywhere...clean your build, delete any current version on the device, make sure both your simulator and your tester's device are set to the same SDK.  If it still doesn't work, perhaps some more context will help (i.e. the controller implementing this view).

Comment: Ok, thank you so i'm not totally blind or stupid ;) I will try cleaning up everything and test it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should examine the crash log:

[Auto upload crashlogs iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876485/auto-upload-crashlogs-iphone/3877106#3877106)

Comment: Thank you! That will help very much (hopefully), great!

Comment: I check the log files and... everything is ok! It was the fault of my "testperson". Thank you!